# Two views for one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listview

I currently have a view page that lists users as a gallery with their image but i also want to create a view page that lists the users by name. I want to use one controller for both of them and i created a `ListView` page and in the orginial `View` page which shows users by image - I have a link to view the `ListView` page. I tried clicking on the link but the page is not showing up. Here is what i have:

**Image view page**

```
 <h2>Users</h2>
<div>
    <a href="~/Views/Users/ListView">Click Here for List view</a>
</div>

<section id="Images">
    <section id="users" data-bind="foreach: Users">
        <div id="nameImage">
            <figure id="content">
                <img width="158" height="158" alt="Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{src: GravatarUrl}"/>
                <figcaption>
                   ...
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <p data-bind="text:Name"></p>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>


@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/user" + ViewBag.Layout.AppVersionForUrls)

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.views.User.GetUser('@url');
    })(jQuery);
</script>
}
```

**List view page**

```
<div class="accordion-inner">
<div data-bind="foreach: Users">
    <div>
        <img width="158" height="158" alt="Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{src: GravatarUrl}"/>
        <p data-bind="text:Name"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 @section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/user" + ViewBag.Layout.AppVersionForUrls)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $.views.User.GetUser('@url');
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    // get the menu from the cache, by Id
    ViewBag.SideBarMenu = SideMenuManager.GetRootMenu(id);
    ViewBag.UserApiURL = "/api/User/" + id.ToString();
    return View(); 
}

public ActionResult ListView(int id)
{
    // get the menu from the cache, by Id
    ViewBag.SideBarMenu = SideMenuManager.GetRootMenu(id);
    ViewBag.RosterApiURL = "/api/User/ListView" + id.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  I don't see a link in either view.

Comment: @cadrell0 the link is in the first code snippet under `<h2>Users</h2>`

Comment: You should go with SWeko's answer.  However, to use "~" in your View, you need to use `@Url.Action("~/Views/Users/ListView")`.  Of course, this will give you a URL to your View, not your controller action, which is not what you want.

Comment: @cadrell0 so what i am trying to do is that i have the view page that displays user images but i will have a toggle button that will change the layout to a list of user names instead of images. Would a partial view be something i should consider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept in MVC is that you never link to views, you link to an action in a controller, that then decides (based on parameters passed) which view and with what model should be rendered. So, if your controller is called UsersController, the

```
<a href="~/Views/Users/ListView">Click Here for List view</a>
```

line should be:

```
<a href="/Users/ListView">Click Here for List view</a>
```

or even better

```
@Html.ActionLink("ListView")
```

Comment: for some reason i am still getting an error but i could see this should work. But i was thinking since i am using this just to change the layout of the page from a grid to a list would it be a better decision to use a partial view?